# Will using the unofficial official combat mod disable achievements?

Tags: steam, achievements, the-witcher-2

So the [new unofficial official Combat Mod](http://redkit.cdprojektred.com/index.php?c=mod&m=show&p=77) from CD PROJEKT RED just came out and I wonder if you will still be able to gain achievements on Steam when you are using this mod to play the game?

Comment: if I haven't played the game to death, I'd consider playing it again with the mod.

Comment: From experience, I know that playing Skyrim with mods does not prevent you from getting achievements (unless the mod itself makes it impossible to earn the achievement). The safest way to verify if the same is true for The Witcher, would be to play the game to a point where you're close to earning another achievement, then trying to earn it with mod. If you don't get the achievement, while the mod is active, you can disable or remove the mod, load the pre-mod save, then earn the achievement.

Comment: @Nolonar That actually depends on the game how it is coded. You can't assume because it is like this in Skyrim, that it is like this in The Witcher. For example, opening the console in Fallout:NV disables achievements until you restart the game.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though people have used other mods and received achievements, but I can't find anything about this mod specifically.

Example - http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/975399-/62619485

Comment: that's correct.  I've installed a few mods for my game while playing and I still got witcher 2 achievements, I don't see why the combat mod would be any different.